# How to perform cross validation for imbalanced datasets in sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification

I have a highly imbalanced dataset and I want to perform a binary classification.

When reading some posts I found that `sklearn` provides `class_weight="balanced"` for imbalanced datasets. So, my classifier code is as follows.

```
clf=RandomForestClassifier(random_state = 42, class_weight="balanced")
```

Then I performed 10 fold cross validation as follows using the above classifier.

```
k_fold = KFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=42)
new_scores = cross_val_score(clf, X, y, cv=k_fold, n_jobs=1)
print(new_scores.mean())
```

However, I am not sure if `class_weight="balanced"` is reflected through 10-fold cross validation. Am I doing it wrong? If so, is there any better way of doing this in sklearn?

I am happy to provide more details if needed.

Comment: There are multiple ways you can balance your dataset (e.g. with replacement or with random sub-sampling), the best depending of the nature of your data, and what you are trying to achieve. you could check out [this package](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/imbalanced-learn), which offers a wide selection.

Comment: Caution: You should wisely choose performense measure(s) for your classifier. You might wanna read when to use which at https://learnerworld.tumblr.com/search/performance+measures
Specifically for skewed data, scores such as F1 score are preferred.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of general cross validation, you might want to use stratified cross validation. More, specifically, you can use [`StratifiedKFold`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold.html).
instead of `KFold` in your code.

This makes sures, that the class imbalances are captured by all potential train and test splits.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer, if I am using `StratifiedKFold`, then should I also use `class_weight="balanced"`? Looking forward to hearing from you :)

Comment: Yes, since the splits are still imbalanced but with almost the same distribution of class labels.